# Can javac stack frame operand verification types be disabled or ignored at class load in java 7?

Tags: java, types

The problem I am facing can be distilled down to this simple example.  Compile this with Oracle java 7 jdk, and then attempt to run it with IBM jre 7 or jre 8.  It fails with NoClassDefFoundError on java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.

```
package org.example;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("got it") ;
        System.out.println(" works "+sb);

        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("other") ;
        sb2.append("killer") ;
        sb2.length() ;
        System.out.println("builder  "+sb2);

        System.out.println( sb == null ? sb2 : sb); 
    }
}
```

Related to http://chrononsystems.com/blog/java-7-design-flaw-leads-to-huge-backward-step-for-the-jvm the java 7 compiler adds stack frames to the byte code which include type verification for the stack operands.

Byte code for this example compiled with Oracle jdk includes:

```
frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
      offset_delta = 0
      locals = [ class "[Ljava/lang/String;", class java/lang/StringBuffer, class java/lang/StringBuilder ]
      stack = [ class java/io/PrintStream, class java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder ]
```

While bytecode from IBM jdk compiler is:

```
frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
      offset_delta = 0
      locals = [ class "[Ljava/lang/String;", class java/lang/StringBuffer, class java/lang/StringBuilder ]
      stack = [ class java/io/PrintStream, class java/io/Serializable ]
```

The stack frame from Oracle resolves to the base class AbstractStringBuilder class.  That class does not exist in IBM JRE rt.jar.  We use Oracle JDK in our build process & I’m reluctant to change that. This java 7 type verification seems to create non-portable bytecode.
Is there a way to disable this type verification checking at either compile time or runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to compile and run Java in different Vendors. I see imports are different. Something might have gone wrong somewhere. Oracle JDK has StringBuilder as well

Try using java.lang.StringBuilder instead of StringBuilder and share what output you are getting.

```
java.lang.StringBuffer sb = new java.lang.StringBuffer("got it") ;
System.out.println(" works "+sb);

java.lang.StringBuilder sb2 = new  java.lang.StringBuilder("other") ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Pratiyash. Here is a little more context & answers to your questions

Comment: Here is a little more context & answers to your questions.  We use support difference jvm vendors to leverage the true promise of java portability. We ship our product to thousands of customers who can run use any jvm vendor form our support platforms. 

Since java 1.4 (& likely earlier!), we have been compiling with sun/oracle jdk and allows our IBM customers to use IBM jvm. It's worked for years. Its now broken with Java 7 requirement on StackMapTable type verification.

Comment: As to why use StringBuffer & StringBuilder together, we'll this simple program is a distillation down to the minimum to illustrate the problem. Our product has > 1 Million lines of code that makes use of StringBuilder & StringBuffer in many different classes. It's never been a problem before. As we migrate our app to Java 7, we encounter these problem.. Rewriting  our applications to eliminate stringbuffer or builder is not a viable option. The question is to find a way to avoid the type verification or impact the way the Oracle compiler examines type inheritance during stack frame creation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice & help. After posting this, we found the root cause. we were using an older version of aspect-j to instrument the classes before packaging them in our application.  Sorry, I never found why the aspect j instrumentation added AbstractStringBuilder to the altered class file.
We were no longer requiring aspect-j.  So removing that solved the problem.

Thanks for the help